webbrowser.open steals focus, how to avoid
On Windows, calling webbrowser.open steals the e.g. keyboard input focus, and sets it to the newly opened webbrowser tab.
Is there a way to avoid this, that is: to open the page in the background ?

The open method has a parameter autoraise=True. If you set this to False,
webbrowser.open('https://example.com', autoraise=False)

it will try to not steal focus, with the heads-up

note that under many window managers this will occur regardless of the setting of this variable.

